# Inbuilt function to find distance

Tags: c++, c

Is there any inbuilt function in c++ or c libraries that can be used to find distance between two points in 2-D space

PS: I know how to implement it myself.

Comment: There are infinitely many valid "distance functions" on 2D space. How is anyone supposed to know which one you want?

Comment: There isn’t even a built-in data structure for points …

Comment: @KerrekSB The French Railway metric, of course.

Comment: @KerrekSB I bet he meant the euclidean distance

Comment: @KonradRudolph doesn't need to be a `point` structure, you could just write a function with 4 input parameters.

Comment: @gokcehan And why would such a function exist in a strongly-typed programming language? That would be counter-purpose.

Comment: @gokcehan: Then she could have said that!

Comment: @KonradRudolph why not? [atan2](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/atan2/) works like this..

Comment: Related: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/hypot.3.html

Comment: @gokcehan Fair point. I don’t agree with that either but yes, obviously it exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you can use arithmetic on [complex numbers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex):

```
using point_t = std::complex<int>;

double distance(point_t a, point_t b) {
    return std::abs(b - a);
}
```

I realise that this doesn’t *quite* fulfil your requirement of not writing your own function but the actual distance logic is implemented in the [`std::norm` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/norm). It just returns the square of the distance.

Comment: From some limited experience I would suggest considering whether the square root is actually a necessary operation. Often you can solve all your problems with the distance-squared alone (remembering that squaring is monotonic), so there's no need to keep this expensive operation.

Comment: @KerrekSB *If* you only need to compare distances, yes. I wanted to keep the answer to the point, though, and I didn’t want to presume a particular use-case.

Comment: Could there be any downsides if replacing the body above with `std::abs(b-a)`? ([`std::abs` from `std::complex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/abs))? Comparing the implementation of `std::norm` and `std::abs` [in libstdc++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/api/a00812_source.html), it seems the latter modifies the length of the real and complex component to the longest one of them,  prior to squaring them. Using the `std::norm` approach will not do any such "component normalization". What could be the up-/downsides to using the `std::abs` (impl.) approach?

Comment: @dfri Indeed, both will work and I think yours might be more efficient or at least on part. Realistically, I’d probably implement this without resorting to complex numbers, using a custom type for points and straightforward application of Pythagoras instead.

Answer (score 4):

With C++11, the [`hypot`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/hypot) function has been added to the standard library.
It computes `sqrt(x^2 + y^2)`, and provides some protection against overflows. It is a convenient way to
find the Euclidean distance between two points:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

struct Point{double x; double y;};

int main()
{
  Point a{0.0, 0.0};
  Point b{3.0, 4.0};

  double distance = std::hypot(a.x-b.x, a.y-b.y);

  std::cout << distance << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Boost.Geometry](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/quickstart.html) claims to have functions for Cartesian and non-Cartesian distance.

Answer (score 1):

No, as a 2D vector is not a type part of the language.

Depending on your needs, there are many math / game / simulation libraries that can be used that implement 2D coordinate objects and will provide you with functions to find the distance between such points.

Comment: why not just a function with signature `double distance(x1, x2, y1, y2)`?

Comment: Because this isn't "inbuilt" - if inbuilt means "part of the language or standard libraries" like I think it does

Answer (score 1):

Well I think it's easy to find:

The linear distance between two points in a 3D Space.

> d = sqrt( ( x2 - x1 )^2 + ( y2 - y1 )^2 + ( z2 - z1 )^2 )

The Manhattan distance is different, very used in 2D games:

> d = | ( x2 - x1 ) | + | ( y2 - y1 ) |

```
typedef struct {
    float x, y, z;
} point_t;

typedef struct {
    int x, y;
} point2d_t;

double distanceFinder( point_t a, point_t b )
{
    return sqrt( pow( a.x-b.x, 2.0 ) + pow( a.y-b.y, 2.0 ) + pow( a.z-b.z, 2.0 ) );
}

int manhattanFinder( point2d_t a, point2d_t b)
{
   /* Considering the points have integer coordinates and is a 2D game */
   return abs( a.x - b.x ) + abs( a.y - b.y );
}
```

Comment: … but the OP has already specified that they know how to implement it themselves.

Comment: don't you need an `abs` in Manhattan distance?

Comment: I think Manhattan distance is still wrong, it should be `d = |(x2-x1)|+|(y2-y1)|` instead.

Comment: Apparently it's not so easy to find :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not so much.

2D distance is a mathematical function, and, if we look at the mathematical functions available to us in C/C++, we find that they operate on numbers.

But that's non-specific: what we actually find is that the functions have different names (in C) or are overloaded (in C++) to operate on different types (int, float, double, &c.) of numbers. Either this, or casting is performed.

Fortunately, there are limited types of numbers so it makes sense to have general libraries to do this kind of thing.

Now, could we construct a 2D distance function in the same way as we construct mathematical functions? You'll immediately see it's more difficult, as there are many ways to represent the points. For instance, cartesian vs. radial, x-y vs. i-j, double vs. float vs. int. Our general 2D distance would need to cover all these possibilities.

Most libraries which have a 2D distance function will have accompanying point structures to reduce the number of possibilities.

However, there is at least one data structure which is implemented that can store a point and be used to find 2D distance using standard libraries: complex numbers!

```
// norm example
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  complex<double> mycomplex (3.0,4.0);

  cout << "The norm of " << mycomplex << " is " << norm(mycomplex) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

But this assumes you're talking about Euclidean distance. You could also be speaking about the Manhatten distance or more exotic metrics. Rather than try to account for all the possibilities I have mentioned, the language designers have opted not to implement this function. (Or any of the many, many other functions such as this which one might reasonably ask this question about).

**EDIT**:
Or you can subtract the points and use the `hypot` function from the C99 standard. See [here](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/hypot.3.html).